# Grails - How to send one ID from view to controller (many-to-many relationship)

Tags: grails, many-to-many, parameter-passing, grails-2.4

I am trying to send an ID of an iterated item but I think the whole list is being sent. How can I send just one ID?
I have `STUDENT` and `COURSE` domain class.

Domain Model

```
class Student {
    String fullName
    String toString() {
        "$fullName"
    }

    static belongsTo = [school: School]
    static hasMany = [courses:Course, studentCourses:StudentCourse]
}

class Course {
    String course
    String toString() {
        "$course"
    }

    static hasMany = [studentCourses:StudentCourse]
    static belongsTo = Student

}

class StudentCourse {
    Student student
    Course course

    //Some methods...
}
```

And this is my edit view.

```
<g:if test="${studentInstance.studentCourses?.course}">
        <g:each class="courseList" in="${studentInstance.studentCourses?.course}" var="courses">
            <li class="courseList">
                <span class="courseList" aria-labelledby="courses-label">${courses.id} ${courses}
                <g:actionSubmitImage class="deleteIcon" action="deleteCourse" value="delete"
                 src="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'delete.png')}" height="17"
                 onclick="return confirm('${message(code: 'default.button.delete.confirm.message', default: 'Are you sure?')}');"
                 params="${courses.id}"/></span>
            </li>
        </g:each>
    </g:if>
```

I'd like to be able to delete one course from the list when user clicks `delete.png` image. But when I `println params.course` the parameter is being sent as a whole list, not as an individual item of the list even though it is within `g:each` tag. How can I just send one corresponding item to the controller?

My edit page has a list of courses.

```
Course 23  English (delete icon here)
       42  Science (delete icon here)
       67  Math (delete icon here)
```

In my `println params.course` this is what I see.

```
[ English, Science, Math ]
```

How can I just have `[English]` when user clicks the delete button next to `English` line?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this happen in every browser or are you seeing this only in IE?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome, but the `println` command is being sent to console from controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I have understand your problem, The problem should be in your taglib

I am giving you the example of similar code and this is working.

```
<g:each in="${student?.studentCourses?.course}" var="course">
<div>
    <span>${course.id} ${course.course}</span>
    <g:link controller="login" action="delete" params="[courseId:course.id]">
        Delete
    </g:link>
</div>
```

In this block of code, by clicking **delete** link with **params** having **params="${[id:course.id]}**, it will redirect to **delete** action inside **login** controller. Print params in delete action and you will get output as
**params: [courseId:2, action:delete, format:null, controller:login]**
Here you can see your **params.courseId** is only a **Long value** not a list.

Hope it will help you understand your problem.

Comment: I tried but it blows up and says cannot print id on null object. However, if I use `params="${[courseId:courses.id]}"` it prints the entire entry like this.

Comment: [startDate:date.struct, school.id:1, school:[id:1], _action_deleteCourse:delete, endDate:date.struct, endDate_month:12, _method:PUT, endDate_day:31, endDate_picker:12/31/2015, endDate_year:2015, version:7, startDate_month:12, _action_deleteCourse.y:14, action_deleteCourse:[_x:15, _y:14], _action_deleteCourse.x:15, startDate_day:7, startDate_year:2011, course:[English, Science, Math], fullName:John Doe, startDate_picker:12/07/2011, id:121, action:update, format:null, controller:student]

Comment: your output shows that you are doing some processing in your taglib. Your taglib is responsible for this output.

Comment: `params="${[courseId:course.id]}"` should be `params="[courseId:course.id]"`. No need for the `${ }`

Comment: change your actionSubmitImage taglib to a simple button and use <g:link> tag instead of actionSubmitImage. You will get your desired output.

Comment: My goodness! It worked. Thank you @Hari Om I used `g:link` tag per your advice but forgot to close it. Instead of `g:actionSumbitImage`, I used `g:link` and `asset image` tag. Thank you.
@Gregg, Thanks for your comment. I got rid of `${ }` but the result was the same. Why is it?